# SSIS Transaction Level for Single Task

Tags: ssis, transaction, rollback

I have 3 tasks in a SSIS package. If the final task fails I only want that task to rollback.

Do I just set that task to REQUIRED? Or leave it as SUPPORTED?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to have happen if task 1 or 2 fails?

Comment: they only select/filter data so no need to rollback

Answer (score 4):

### SSIS Transaction Level

The default transaction level for all tasks and containers is `Supported` which means they will enlist in an transaction if available but they will not create one..

A `Required` settings will start a transaction if one does not exist and enlist in an existing transaction.

`NotSupported` indicates that the Executable/Container will ignore any existing transactions which may result in deadlocks depending on your design.

### Your case

You have 3 Tasks and the desire is to have the third item behave in an atomic way. The answer is, partially, that you'll want to set the Transaction option to `Required`. *Partially* because you **can** commit throughout your data load. In an OLE DB Destination, if you have a non-zero commit size then the committed data is fully committed. A rollback isn't going to pull that data back out.